# Is it possible to get Proxy setitings's Useranme and password from Mac system settings?

Tags: objective-c

I want my application to read the proxy settings information from the mac os settings,

i want to read the proxy server url and proxy username and password too...

Im able to read the proxy server url using scdyanmiccopyproxy() function, but 
Is it possible to read the proxy username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's kept in the keychain. You can see that using `Keychain Access.app`, under the entry labeled by the proxy server URL. To obtain  it programmatically, you need to use the [Keychain Service](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html). There's a helpful Cocoa wrapper too, see [EMKeychain](http://extendmac.com/EMKeychain/).